# Sorting a weird data structure based on time, python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7

Working with python here. I have a dictionary storing 5 different items like so:
Unpopulated:

```
{1:[], 2:[], 3:[], 4:[], 5:[]}
```

So basically, a dictionary with 5 int keys, each holding an array.

Populated: (short example)

```
{1: [['04:08', '3'], ['05:54', '2'], ['00:48', '5']], 2:[['18:19', '2'], ['20:40', '4'],['06:54', '2']] 3:['12:22', '3'], ['10:42', '1']], 4:[['16:16', '3'], ['15:09', '1']], 5:[['16:54', '2'], ['21:48', '1'], ['21:26', '1']]}.
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to *sort the stored arrays by the first value (int representing time)*? I want to be able to iterate through the populated structure from 00:00 -> 23:59, for each key,1-5. (will hold all times when fully populated).

If it helps, this is how I'm setting up the *weird* data structure

```
curClus = int(getCluster(curDate, numClusters, numIteration)) //returns an int range of 1-5
dictStorage[curClus].append([curTime, curZone]) //stored in key value of curClus
```

Example output I'm *currently* getting:

```
{1: [['04:08', '3'], ['05:54', '2'], ['00:48', '5']], 2:[['18:19', '2'], ['20:40', '4'],['06:54', '2']] 3:['12:22', '3'], ['10:42', '1']], 4:[['16:16', '3'], ['15:09', '1']], 5:[['16:54', '2'], ['21:48', '1'], ['21:26', '1']]}.
```

example output I'm looking for:

```
{1: [['00:48', '5'], ['04:08', '3'], ['05:54', '2']], 2:[['06:54', '2'],['18:19', '2'], ['20:40', '4']] 3:[['10:42', '1'],['12:22', '3']], 4:[['15:09', '1'], ['16:16', '3']], 5:[['16:54', '2'], '21:26', '1'],['21:48', '1']]}.
```

Comment: Aren't they already sorted by time?

Comment: No. This was just a short example. I'm basically iterating through ~20k data points that represent days / times, so the times are incrementing upwards for day 1, then reset for day 2. I just didn't include a large enough example above where day 2 was hit. @Peilonrayz

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of your expected output for this sample?

Comment: If they keys are always 1-5 (or 1-N), why use a dictionary rather than a list?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy just did.

Comment: @0x5453 Post that as an answer.

Comment: @0x5453 don't think so, or maybe you used wrong variable name? curClus is returning a single int variable each iteration and is not storing the dictionary.

Comment: @E.Goldsmi Right, sorry, misread your example.  I've moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```
dictStorageSorted = {k: sorted(v, key=lambda v: v[0]) for k, v in dictStorage.items()}
```